# How can I mount devices as a normal user?

Tags: mount, permissions

Is it possible to mount some devices without being root and without having sudo permissions?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do it using [**`pmount`**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/pmount.1.html).

`man pmount`

```
NAME
       pmount - mount arbitrary hotpluggable devices as normal user

pmount <device> [ label ]
```

Example:

```
 pmount /dev/sdb1 flash_drive
```

This will mount the device `/dev/sdb1` at `/media/flash_drive`.

Policy:

The mount will succeed if all of the following conditions are met:

```
   · device is a block device in /dev/

   · device is not in /etc/fstab (if it is, pmount executes  mount  device
     as the calling user to handle this transparently). See below for more
     details.

   · device is not already mounted according to /etc/mtab and /proc/mounts

   · if the mount point already exists, there is no device already mounted
     at it and the directory is empty

   · device   is   removable   (USB,   FireWire,   or   MMC   device,   or
     /sys/block/drive/removable is 1) or whitelisted in /etc/pmount.allow.

   · device is not locked
```

To unmount the device, use pumount, like so:

```
pumount <device>
```

Example:

```
 pumount /dev/sdb1
```